# How can I simultaneously connect my computer to an USB tethering mobile phone while retaining wi-fi Internet connectivity?

Tags: wireless, usb, ethernet

How can I simultaneously connect my computer to an USB tethering mobile phone while retaining wi-fi Internet connectivity?

Hello,

My laptop is connected to my mobile phone with a USB cable. The mobile phone (Samsung Galaxy S5) has USB tethering turned on. This way i am controlling my computer from the phone using SSH and VNC. The mobile phone cannot use 3G because I only have access to wi-fi Internet.

The problem is that I don't have Internet connectivity for the laptop in this scenario.

I want to simultaneously have the computer connected over wi-fi to the Internet through a router.

Now, back in the bad old days when I was still using Windows I used to have this laptop connected to a LAN and wi-fi Internet simultaneously and that was working so there is probably a way to do this.

Summary:

- Laptop connected to mobile phone over USB cable
- Mobile phone has USB tethering turned on
- Mobile phone is controlling laptop using SSH and VNC
- Mobile phone cannot use 3G
- There seems to be some restriction with the phone so it cannot have a wifi connection and do USB tethering at the same time
- I want to simultaneously use wi-fi on the computer to connect to the Internet OR if there is a way to keep wifi connection on the mobile phone on and sharing that with the computer over USB that couold work too

Vesa

Ubuntu 15.10